loading image sequenz into cache with img.onload
I load a series of images at the start of the site, when all images are loaded the first image is displayed. Everything is fine in the network tab of the debugger, each image is displayed with 200.
Now the user can control the sequence via touchmove on the image. Depending on the X position on the image, a new path is generated and the image changes. If the images are local, it works fine, but the server is really lagging.
I thought that once I had loaded the images, they would be used from the cache?!?
Why not?
 const loadOneImage = (url) => {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          checkLoadingFinishedOK(url);
          resolve(url);
        };

        img.onerror = function() {
          checkLoadingFinishedNOOK(url);
          reject(url);
        };
        img.src = url;
      });
    };

the image is displayed via Vue :src="path"
while dragging the mouse over the image only when I stop dragging the mouse the image is displayed. But the path is exactly the same as the one from the preloader, where the image was loaded.


Can you clarify what the question is? Why an image isn't loaded from browser cache or something else?

ok, I add the info to the question

And what is the problem? That 137 and 200 aren't loaded from cache while you expected them to? The way cache works totally depends on a server. Make sure you don't have "disable cache" in dev tools which would have the obvious effect

137 and 200 are displayed, the others (Canceld) are not displayed!

you're right, the cache was deactivated, sorry... but now an image is still occasionally cancelled.

It needs to be debugged why there are "canceled" in your case. Please, provide a workable demo if possible
